# Look for error message causing red marker in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, locate, package-explorer

Sometimes I see error markers (red X icon) near some files in Eclipse package explorer, but can't find any corresponding error neither in the file itself, nor in the problems view.

I there any common way to see what Eclipse thinks is an error for specific file with marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be many things, but is usually either compilation problems or Validaton issues (xml, jsp validation etc.)

Check the `Problems` tab to see if you get any tip. Check also build path page in Project Preferences to see if there is any compilation issue.

Comment: I don't need to find an error, I wish to learn if general button like "what is wrong" exists in Eclipse?

Comment: Usually, they appear on `Problems` or `Error Log` tabs. To open those tabs (if they aren't shown), go to `Window > Show View` option

Answer (score 1):

Check the project properties. A missing JAR might be causing the problem, or any other issues on the classpath.

Right click the project, Properties, Java Build Path. Check if there are errors there.

Comment: Another hint is to do a full clean. Right click on the project, Refresh (F5), wait a second, then click on the Project upper menu and then Clean.